# Black screen after sudo systemctl stop gdm

Tags: boot, screen, gdm

I had a problem with my NoMachine Programm so I decided to use the possible solutions from their website: https://knowledgebase.nomachine.com/AR03P00973
I tried the commands in the graphical desktop environment:
`sudo systemctl stop lightdm` and `sudo systemctl stop display-manager` and both put me in a blackscreen where I couldn't do anything except rebooting my PC. After I rebooted my PC there was no blackscreen anymore. Then I tried the command: `sudo systemctl stop gdm` and after this command I'm still in the blackscreen even after rebooting. And I also cant see my cursor. I can't even get to the Bios because the screen is just black. Maybe switching between the TTY screen is working but I cant tell since I cant see what is happening. I dont know what to do. I now know that I shouldn't have used these commands in the normal graphical desktop environment.

I'm using the Version 20.04.3

---

I'm afraid none of these solutions helped. I turned my PC on tried all the TTY screens but all of them gave me a black screen. I even tried to log in, open the console, and type in the command for restarting the display-manager but no matter what I did there was still no video signal. I'm using the version: 20.04.3

Comment: Please [Edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1386409/edit) and include the version of Ubuntu you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out what the problem was. The problem was something in the BIOS so I had to reset my BIOS manually and everything worked again. Nonetheless I want to thank everyone who tried to help me.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you stop your display manager, you need to do so through a TTY console so that you don't lose your session. You will need to go to a TTY screen and log in with your username and password so you can run commands.

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> to open a TTY screen (TTY4).

Then, sign in with your username and password.

Now, you can run the commands listed in the help article.

```
sudo systemctl stop display-manager
sudo /etc/NX/nxserver --restart
```

I'm not sure which screen this will start the GUI. The GUI usually runs on TTY1 or TTY2 but sometimes runs on TTY7.

Use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to get to TTY1, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to get to TTY2, or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> to get to TTY7. Try all three of these to see if you can find a working session.

Alternatively, to get back to a normal GUI desktop, you can always startup your display manager using the following command:

```
sudo systemctl restart display-manager
```

and your default Ubuntu desktop or login screen should be on TTY1 or TTY2 or possibly TTY7.

Comment: If all else fails, check the other tty screens like TTY5, 6, 8, and 9.

Comment: Also, this is nearly always the fix (or partial fix) for a black screen. You can sign in and run commands, even when your display manager is not running or will not run.